# Casting a SeekableByteChannel to a FileChannel

Tags: java, io, nio

Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) oracle java tutorial:

> The following code snippet opens a file for both reading and writing
>   by using one of the newByteChannel methods. The SeekableByteChannel
>   that is returned is cast to a FileChannel.

This is the snippet they are talking about present in the same link I above mentioned.

```
String s = "I was here!\n";
byte data[] = s.getBytes();
ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

ByteBuffer copy = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);

try (FileChannel fc = (FileChannel.open(file, READ, WRITE))) {
    // Read the first 12
    // bytes of the file.
    int nread;
    do {
        nread = fc.read(copy);
    } while (nread != -1 && copy.hasRemaining());

    // Write "I was here!" at the beginning of the file.
    fc.position(0);
    while (out.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(out);
    out.rewind();

    // Move to the end of the file.  Copy the first 12 bytes to
    // the end of the file.  Then write "I was here!" again.
    long length = fc.size();
    fc.position(length-1);
    copy.flip();
    while (copy.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(copy);
    while (out.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(out);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.out.println("I/O Exception: " + x);
}
```

So basically they are talking about a Files.newByteChannel() method which returns a SeekableByteChannel object which in turn gets cast to a FileChannel. 
Well, I do not see this process. Is it hidden/running on the background/ or anyother sourcery magic kind of thing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It returns an object which implements SeekableByteChannel and which extends FileChannel. No background process, no sorcery, no magic. Just computation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived class (or Interface) as the target. So if FileChannel.open() returns a SeekableByteChannel, you can use the assignment to a FileChannel (as shown in your example) as long as SeekableByteChannel is derived from FileChannel or FileChannel is an interface implemented by SeekableByteChannel.

I wouldn't have used the term "cast" in this case though, because this is done implicit.

Just to clarify: I would use the term "cast" when the objects are unknown to the compiler or unrelated.

i.E. in C I could cast a char * to an int * and it would work as long as I know what I'm doing.

In Java if I have code like this:

```
Object a = new String();
String b = (String)a;
```

The compiler doesn't know what a is and I really have to use a cast. If the compiler knows the hierarchy and it is valid for the target, you don't need to specify a cast, which is what is happening in the above example. The compiler knows the types and that they are safe.

Comment: Yep Actually it returns a FileChannel, however as you underlined FileChannel implements SeekableByteChannel so is-a SeekableByteChannel, therefore no issues. Thanks for the prompt response